# Desktop App Converter Error E_MANIFEST_USE_DEFAULT_VALUE_FAILED

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I am trying to convert my app for the windows store using Desktop App Converter and  I am stuck with this command which gives me the same error no matter what I try, can anyone have a clue what am I doing wrong here?

in powershell command line:

```
$binDirectory = "C:\appIn\appSetup.msi"
$appExecutable = "app.exe"
$packageDirectory = "C:\appOut"
$packageName = "appPackName"
$publisher = "CN=DA7DD138-DCEF-7891-1234-A12C7B024C71"
$appDisplayName = "App Name"
$appDescription = "Literally 1 click app for..."
$packageDisplayName = "Literally 1 click app for..."
$packagePublisherDisplayName = "AppdispName"
$version = "1.0.0.0"
cls; DesktopAppConverter -Installer $binDirectory -AppExecutable $appExecutable -Destination $packageDirectory -PackageName $packageName -Publisher $publisher -AppDisplayName $appDisplayName -AppDescription $appDescription -PackageDisplayName $packageDisplayName -PackagePublisherDisplayName $packagePublisherDisplayName -Verbose -Version $version
```

the error I get is

*Inner Exception[0]: System.ArgumentException: DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_MANIFEST_USE_DEFAULT_VALUE_FAILED': Property 'Package.Applications.Application.Id' in AppxManifest.xml could not be set to the default value 'appPackName' given for parameter '-PackageName'. Please visit: 'https://aka.ms/appid' for more info on the Data type requirements for the property, and retry with a valid value or pass in a value for optional parameter ’-AppId’ to override the default VERBOSE: The full error record is saved in the logs at C:\DesktopAppConverter\be4346f6-b6f9-4d6d-8864-97a7834a247f\logs*

I have tried all combinations for package name, with values found in the dev center... nothing works; what am I doing wrong here?

**thank you**

Answer (score 1):

From your error info, it is the 'Package.Applications.Application.Id' in AppxManifest.xml could not be set to the default value 'appPackName' given for parameter '-PackageName'.

As the **-AppId**  Package manifest parameters introduction in the [Parameter Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter#parameter-reference),

> **-AppId  Optional**  Specifies a value to set Application Id to in the Windows app package manifest. If it is not specified, it will be set to the value passed in for PackageName. In many cases, using the PackageName is fine. However, if the dev center assigns an identity to your package that begins with a number, make sure that you also pass in the -AppId parameter, and use only the string suffix (after the period separator) as the value of that parameter.

So you can try to pass in the **-AppId** parameter when convert your app, and use only the string suffix (after the period separator) as the value of that parameter.

Comment: Having same problem - an example would greatly help. Not finding that anywhere - if I finally deduce what this means I'll convert to example!